# tensorflow 2.3.0 module error in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to import tensorflow into my system.

while importing I am getting the below error message.

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Kindly help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: plz try to add details about which platform you are trying to install like mac, windows, linux or from anaconda?

Comment: i am using windows machine and i am facing same issue in all IDE.

Comment: did you install the package by using `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: i already install tensorflow 2.3.0

Comment: anaconda or open-source? are you tried any virtual environment?

Comment: ya i tried but still its showing the same error

Comment: in jupyter notebook the error its showing is ( Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.)

Comment: Did you install TensorFlow in your virtual environment or on your default environment?

Comment: when you installed tensorflow  you installed it in a certain environment. Make sure the python program you are executing is in the same environment in which you installed tensorflow